# preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have fresh install laravel project

but when I try to use blade template engine, it gave me this error

[image: preg_replace_callback():]

It says :

> preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: internal error: previously-checked referenced subpattern not found at offset 47

I just rename the view file from "hello.php" to "hello.blade.php"

**PHP Version : 5.4.7**

anyone know about this error?

Comment: Could you post the view code?

Comment: what version of php are you running?

Comment: @DamienPirsy : The view code is the hello.php default by laravel, I just renamed it to hello.blade.php

Comment: @TheShiftExchange : php 5.4.7

Comment: Did you run computer update after downloading Laravel?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange : yes sir

Comment: What if you clear the contents of the hello.blade.php to just something like "hi" - does that show up?

Comment: I try to move to another server with different version of apache and php and it's worked

Comment: Hey I'm facing the same problem. Can you tell to which apache and php version you switched to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Change your ***BladeCompiler.php*** with the one given in the link below:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a1c5dd80aa6a13e0f8cf1f0e0e1700ff65c11f2c/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php

P.S. You will find ***BladeCompiler.php*** file **inside your laravel_project directory** at ***./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php***

Comment: Haha, It's a little bit too late

I've move on another server with latest php version

btw Thanks :D

Comment: It was for others who might face the same issue buddy.